# Correct way to get refs and attach event listeners in React ComponentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

The problem is roughly summarized in the comments in the code snippet. When I bind `this._setSize` in `constructor`, it never knows about `this.container` — even when called in `componentDidMount`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```js
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this._setSize = this._setSize.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const container = this.container // <div></div> :)
    this._setSize()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this._setSize)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this._setSize)
  } 

  _setSize () {
    const container = this.container // undefined :(
    const containerSize = {
      x: container.offsetWidth,
      y: container.offsetHeight
    }
    this.setState({ containerSize })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div ref={node => this.container = node}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Within each re-render you are creating and passing new instance of function to setup container ref. The previous function is then called with `null`. Therefore it might happen that you accidently set `this.container` to `null`:

```js
<div ref={node => this.container = node}>
```

When you pass here component instance method instead of inline function, it is called once with reference and second time with `null` during component unmount. E.g.:

```js
// dont forget to bind it in constructor
onContainerRef (node) {
  // furthermore you can even check if node is not null
  // if (node) { ...
  this.container = node
} 

// ... in render
<div ref={this.onContainerRef}>
```

You can read more in [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code and it's working now: [see working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zaweji/1/edit?js,console,output)

What was the problem?

```
componentWillUnmount () {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this._setSize)
}
```

You didn't remove event listener from `window` because in `componentWillUnmount` you have `addEventListener` instead of `removeEventListener`. If you have any conditional rendering of the component, on `resize` event `_setSize` will be also called.

To illustrate this problem, play with the broken demo and click on `Toggle` button and look at output: [see broken DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zaweji/2/edit?js,console,output)